# Annotating maths formulas?

Tags: math-mode, annotations

Is it possible to draw annotations inside math formulas ? I want to see if it helps for pedagogical purposes.

For example I would like to draw the arrow in red between the two symbols in the following formula, to highlight the fact that they are the same:

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt,landscape,a4paper]{article}    
\begin{document}

$$ P ( \xi \in B )  = \int_B f_{\xi} dx $$

\end{document}
```

Comment: Can be much easier if you choose a certain color instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quite easy with `pst-node`: define both B's as `rnode`s and connect them by one of the node connections.

*Unrelated*: don't use  `$$ … $$` in LaTeX, this is a plain TeX syntax, and you'll have bad vertical spacing. Use  `\[ … \]` instead.

```
\documentclass[10pt,landscape,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{pst-node}

\begin{document}

\[
 P ( \xi \in \rnode{B1}{B} ) = \int_{\rnode{B2}{B}} f_{\xi} dx
 \psset{arrowinset=0.1, linejoin=1}
 \ncbar[linecolor=red, angle=-90, nodesep=2pt]{<->}{B1}{B2}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

You can do that with tikz:

```
\documentclass[10pt,landscape,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage    {tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{babel} % for issues with some babel packages
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}

\begin{document}
\[ P ( \xi \in \tikzmarknode{B1}B ) = \int_{\tikzmarknode{B2}B} f_{\xi}\,dx \]
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
\draw[<->,red,out=-100,in=-100] ([yshift=-2pt]B1.south) to ([yshift=-2pt]B2.south);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]